# Brownian Motion: direct integration vs. using Ito's lemma

Tags: black-scholes, finance, derivatives, brownian-motion, brownian

I have a dilemma that I can't figure out.

The brownian motion has the following stochastic differential equation:

dS=μSdt+σSdW

As known, Ito's lemma is used to solve the SDE, by setting f=log(S), which results in:

∫df=∫(μ−1/2σ^2)dt + ∫σdW

which is equal to:

ln(S(T)/s(0))=(μ−1/2σ^2)T + σW(T).

Now, if instead of applying Ito, I go straight doing the integrals I have:

∫(1/S)dS = ln(S(T)/s(0)), since d(log(S))/ds = 1/s

and ∫μdt + ∫σdW = μT + σW(T).

Then:

ln(S(T)/s(0))=μT + σW(T).

which is different from the above result by the term (-1/2σ^2)T.

Why do I get 2 different results if integrating directly, or applying Ito's lemma? Am I missing something?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: This has been covered on this site. Please use the search to find some relevant answers.

Comment: "dS" is not small enough for a integral to be defined.